# How to write an event for already selected radio button?

Tags: php, javascript, radio-button

My code snippet for radio buttons is -

```
<input type="radio" name="isPush" id="isPushYes" <? if($isPush) {?>checked="checked"<?}?> value="<?= $isPush;?>" > <? echo "Yes"?></input>
<input type="radio" name="isPush" id="isPushNo" <? if(!$isPush) {?>checked="checked"<?}?> value="<?= $isPush;?>" > <? echo "No"?></input>
<table id="emailTable"><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>
```

The value of **isPush** will be 0 or 1. So one of my radio buttons will always be selected. And selecting either of the radio buttons initially is not in my hands.

Now, For the table, I want to set `display: none` when when second radio button is selected and set `display: visible` when first radio button is selected.

So which **event** should I put? I certainly can't put *onclick*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the selected radio onload, as well as onchange. This means the table will be hidden to start with, if `No` is selected by default.

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SKb3r/2/)**

```
function checkRadio()
{
        var tbl = document.getElementById("emailTable");

        if(document.getElementById("isPushYes").checked)
        {
           tbl.style.display = "";
        }
        else
        {
            tbl.style.display = "none";
        }   
}

window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById("isPushYes").onchange = checkRadio;
    document.getElementById("isPushNo").onchange = checkRadio;

    checkRadio();
}​
```

Another option is without the onload event, you set the display with PHP:

```
<table id="emailTable" <?php if(!$isPush) echo 'style="display:none"'; ?>><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: yes. I will try this. but is there another way without the onload event of the page. What if I want to do it with radio button's event.

Comment: It uses both the onload and the radio's onchange events. If you don't use onload then you can't hide/show the table like you want.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what you want:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="myradio" value="1" checked="true" onchange="hideActive(this.name);" /> radio 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="myradio" value="2" onchange="hideActive(this.name);" /> radio 2</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="myradio" value="3" onchange="hideActive(this.name);" /> radio 3</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideActive(radioGroupName) {
        var all = document.getElementsByName(radioGroupName);
        for(var n = 0; n < all.length; n++) {
            if(true === all[n].checked) {
                all[n].setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
            }
            else {
                all[n].removeAttribute('style');
            }

        }
    }

    hideActive('myradio');
</script>
```

if you support jquery try this

```
<label><input type="radio" name="myradio" value="1" checked="true" /> radio 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="myradio" value="2" /> radio 2</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="myradio" value="3" /> radio 3</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        var all = jQuery('input[name=myradio]');
        var change = function() {
            all
                .show()
                .filter(':checked').hide();
        };
        all.change(function(){
            change();
        });

        //call init
        change();


    });
</script>
```

Comment: If `$isPush = 1`. so first radio is automatically selected. I didn't select it by myself. but I want to do some action when first radio button is selected. is there some action like _onselect_? please help

Comment: its better to call this action by a javascript... my sample call the "change" method by loading

Answer (score 0):

You want to perform some action when the radio button is checked by the user, so you'll want to bind a handler for the `onchange` event.

Comment: I am not doing the change initially. I will do the selection afterwards. when `$isPush = 1` I want to do event1 and when `$isPush = 0` I want to do event2.

Comment: @HussainTamboli Your initial state should be set in your PHP code, using your PHP variable (`$isPush`), in the same way that you're using PHP to set the correct radio button as `checked`. Doing it on page load with JavaScript is totally unnecessary, and in my opinion bad practice. Reacting to a different radio button being selected by the user after the page has loaded should be handled using JavaScript, in response to the `onchange` event.

Comment: So If I don't use _onload_ I can't achieve what I want here. Suppose I am not using the radio buttons, what will be the alternate design.

Comment: I can put it like this- `<? if($isPush) {?> <table></table><? }?>`. right?

Comment: @HussainTamboli You *could* use `onload`, but there's absolutely no need to do so. The end result you're looking for is the page to load with the table either visible or hidden, depending on the value of `$isPush` (which, again, is a PHP variable); you can set the relevant style attribute on the table for the initial state **in your PHP code**, you **don't need to use** JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

here is the fidddle..
http://jsfiddle.net/vfuV5/2/

for example:

```
if($('input:radio[name="isPush"]:checked').val() == 'Yes')  // used yes u can use 1 here
{
        $('#emailTable').show();                            
}else{
    $('#emailTable').hide();
}

$("input[name='isPush']").change(function() {
  if($('input:radio[name="isPush"]:checked').val() == 'Yes')  // used yes u can use 1 here
  {
        $('#emailTable').show();                            
  }else{
    $('#emailTable').hide();
  }
});
```

**OR**

make a function

```
function checkRadioValue()
{
    if($('input:radio[name="isPush"]:checked').val() == 'Yes')  // used yes u can use 1 here
    {
        $('#emailTable').show();                            
    }else{
       $('#emailTable').hide();
    }
}
```

Call this function on document.ready and onchange function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkRadioValue();
    $("input[name='isPush']").change(function() {
          checkRadioValue();
    });


})
```

Comment: i think the answer was without jquery

Comment: I am not doing any change initially. the state of selection of radio button will be set by the value of the variable : '$isPush' . I will be selecting either of them afterwards.

Comment: I actually want something like - `<? if($isPush) {?> <table></table><? }?>` and when second radio is selected do `$isPush = 0` and hide the table. Again when first radio is selected do `$isPush = 1` and display the table.

Comment: Hey, I am trying to put it into my file.js . But it doesn't even work when I put `onchange = checkRadioValue()`. But this seems to be the promising way.

Comment: this should work.... ok i missed to call function before `checkRadioValue()`... updated the answer.. please check... let me know if therez any problem..  which i am sure there won't be any..:)

Answer (score 0):

I personally would look at onChange, this will catch occasions where the selected value changes. If doing this in jquery I'd do something like:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=isPush]').bind('change', function(e){
 console.log('We had a change');
});
```

Note that if the item is dynamically added at all you should change bind to live.

Comment: How do I handle the initially selected radio button. if `$isPush = 1` first radio button will be automatically selected, for this event of automatic selection I want to put an event. how do I do that?

Comment: hey can't do this with _onchange_

Comment: I've tweaked my code as the selector was wrong. Are you using JQuery? If not, the code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

you should write a javascript function that changes the display attribute and then call it in 2 places.

1- When the document loads.

> window.onload = function () { javascript_function(); }

if you have JQuery you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    javascript_function();
)};
```

2- When there's a change in the radio button.

Either set a `onchange="javascript_function"` or use JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    javascript_function();
    $("#radio_id").change(javascript_function());
)};
```

Comment: Isn't there something without the _onload_ event.

Answer (score 0):

Its a test. Change it as like as you want

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function fnc(myid,otherid)
{
if(document.getElementById(myid).checked)
{document.getElementById(otherid).disabled='disabled';}
}
</script>

<input type="radio" name="isPush" id="isPushYes" onchange="fnc(this.id,'isPushNo')">
<input type="radio" name="isPush" id="isPushNo" onchange="fnc(this.id,'isPushYes')">
```

Comment: suppose `$isPush = 1`. so it will select first radio button automatically. then how do I use _onchange_. I am not doing any change. although when firs radio is selected implicitly I want to perform some action.

Comment: then you should put a button like "enable" or something like that,  onclick which will open the disabled radio and again you choose another one

Answer (score 0):

Onchange, for example (in JQuery):

```
$('input[name="isPush"]').change(function() {
// your code
});
```

Or:

```
<input onchange="myFunction();" type="radio" name="isPush" id="isPushYes" <? if($isPush) {?>checked="checked"<?}?> value="<?= $isPush;?>" > <? echo "Yes"?></input>
<input onchange="myFunction();" type="radio" name="isPush" id="isPushNo" <? if(!$isPush) {?>checked="checked"<?}?> value="<?= $isPush;?>" > <? echo "No"?></input>
```